# build custom shipping method like cod with some extra fields

Tags: shipping-methods

i want to create custom shippinng filed to cash on deliver .may be like cod comment a simple text box that will showwhen user selects cod.

How can i do it via module or is there any module or plugin for that , pls guide uf for the same

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cashondelivery.html

also on git: https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento-CashOnDelivery

Comment: but i want user to add custom field like user inputs  cod by abc in USd or whatever he inputs